# Safari print with Javascript produces blank when printing an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have read up on all issues regarding Safari and blank printing. It seems that a white flash happens, re-rendering the page, and content of the iframe is lost before a print dialog can grab it.

Here is my javascript - It works in all browsers except safari. It brings up the dialog, but prints a blank page.

```
function PrintPopupCode(id) {
```

`framedoc = document;

   var popupFrame = $(framedoc).find("#" + id + '\\!PopupFrame');
   var icontentWindow = popupFrame[0].contentWindow || popupFrame[0].contentDocument;
   icontentWindow.focus();
   icontentWindow.print();
}
function PrintPopup(id) {

   setTimeout(function () { PrintPopupCode(id) }, 3000);
}`

I have set a timeout, i previously read it would help if the transfer of content took sometime, but it has not helped.

I have also tried with printElement() function on the icontentWindow variable, but it does not support this method.

[Print Element Method](https://raw.github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/master/jQuery.printElement/jquery.printElement.js)

This is all in a .js file, and not on the page. I have tried on the page, but the same thing happens.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
function PrintPopupCode(id) {
   framedoc = document;

   var popupFrame = $(framedoc).find("#" + id + '\\!PopupFrame');
   var icontentWindow = popupFrame[0].contentWindow || popupFrame[0].contentDocument;
   icontentWindow.focus();
   setTimeout(icontentWindow.print, 3000);
}

function PrintPopup(id) {

   PrintPopupCode(id);
}
```